# xamarin scrollview jumping when adding children

Tags: c#, xamarin, android-scrollview

I have a `<ScrollView/>` which contains a `<Grid/>` (of `<images/>`), when the user nears the bottom of the scrollview I connect to a website and download the next set of images (actually, JSON's containing links for ImageSource's) which creates an "endless" scroll box of images.

my issue is that when i download the next set of images the app momentarily hangs and the scrollbox then jumps to catch up as the new set is added. **how can i prevent this "Jumping"?**

```
    private async void OnScrolled(object sender, ScrolledEventArgs e)
    {
        ScrollView scroller = (ScrollView)sender;
        //threshhold == bottom of scrollveiw + height of one image (aka just before it's visible)
        double threashold = (e.ScrollY + scroller.Height) + preview_size;

        //if we touch the threshhold...
        if (threashold > scroller.ContentSize.Height)
        {
            //one row of images
            int TilePreload = (Tiles.Count + ColCount);

            //if the next row exceeds the total available post count, download and append more posts
            if (TilePreload >= Posts.Count)
            {
                //we have reached the end of our postlist, we must get more!
                var results = await Task.Run(()=>FetchResults<List<CPost>>());
                Posts.AddRange( results);
            }

            //then, add the tiles to UI 
            //AddRow();// <- jumpy

            //calling this as a task results in no tiles added, and eventually an execption
            await Task.Run( () => AddRow() );
        }
    }
```

//seperated the for loop as function so it can be ran as a task (if required)

```
    public void AddRow()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < RowCount; i++)
        {
            //wrapper for assigning Image to Grid
            //aka ImageSourec = some URL
            AddTile(i);
        }
    }
```

note: `FetchResults<T>();` is more or less a wrapper for

```
//fyi using System.Net.Http;
public static string GetResponse(string page, Dictionary<String, String> arguments, bool IsPost = false)
{
    HttpMethod Method = IsPost ? HttpMethod.Post : HttpMethod.Get;

    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(Method, page)
    {
        Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(arguments)
    };

    HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = Client.SendAsync(request).Result;
    if (httpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        return httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: The `OnScrolled` method is not async so it's probably blocking the UI until your `Task` result comes back.... think about it... even if the `Task` is async, your `OnScrolled` (which is using `ScrollEventArgs`) cannot complete until it gets a return                 `var results = FetchResults<List<CPost>>();
                
                Posts.AddRange( results );`.  

Have you tried marking `OnScrolled` as async and then using `Task.Run` to get your result?  I can't test it ATM but that might prevent the UI from blocking while your request is processed.

Comment: I updated the Post to reflect the async ver. its still jumpy (although less), AddTile() is where the ImageSource URI is assigned, which could be causing it i guess, but calling AddTile() as a task seems to fail (no tiles added) and eventually threw some SSL connection exception :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are updating the UI, that needs to be done on the main UI thread.

When you call

```
await Task.Run( () => AddRow() );
```

That means that AddRow (and any methods it calls) are not running on the UI thread and will cause a crash.

What you might try is something like this (not tested):

```
private async void OnScrolled(object sender, ScrolledEventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Run(async () => 
    {
        ScrollView scroller = (ScrollView)sender;
        //threshhold == bottom of scrollveiw + height of one image (aka just before it's visible)
        double threashold = (e.ScrollY + scroller.Height) + preview_size;

        //if we touch the threshhold...
        if (threashold > scroller.ContentSize.Height)
        {
            //one row of images
            int TilePreload = (Tiles.Count + ColCount);

            //if the next row exceeds the total available post count, download and append more posts
            if (TilePreload >= Posts.Count)
            {
                //we have reached the end of our postlist, we must get more!
                var results = await Task.Run(()=>FetchResults<List<CPost>>()).ConfigureAwait(false);
                Posts.AddRange( results);
            }
        }
    });

    //then, add the tiles to UI 
    AddRow();
}
```

Also, Why isn't GetResponse an async method?? (using `.Result` blocks the thread) And thus why isn't FetchResults>() not async?

To make GetResponse async:

```
public static async Task<string> GetResponse(string page, Dictionary<String, String> arguments, bool IsPost = false)
{
    HttpMethod Method = IsPost ? HttpMethod.Post : HttpMethod.Get;

    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(Method, page)
    {
        Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(arguments)
    };

    HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = await Client.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);
    if (httpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        return await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
    return null;
}
```

The way you had it, you had a lot of thread jumping around and code blocking threads due to use of `.Result`
So by putting all of the code that does not require running on the UI thread inside a Task, you can avoid any code running on the UI thread until you need it to, i.e. when you add the UI elements.

Using `.ConfigureAwait(false)` means when that task ends, the following code will not be marshaled back to the calling thread, saving some thread marshalling, which takes time. When `.ConfigureAwait(false)` is not called the default is `.ConfigureAwait(true)` which means "When this task is done, marshal the following code back to the thread this task was called from. So by doing the above you should avoid some threading delays and hopefully this will resolve the jumpiness.

Though you may need to do a test because with the above, the OnScrolled event will continue to be fired while that work is being completed. So you may want to flag to only run the code to get the new items once, e.g.:

```
bool _isGettingNewItems;
private async void OnScrolled(object sender, ScrolledEventArgs e)
{
    // Don't run the code to get new items if it is already running
    if (_isGettingNewItems) 
        return;

    _isGettingNewItems = true;
    await Task.Run(async () => 
    {
        ...
    });

    //then, add the tiles to UI 
    AddRow();

    // finished getting new items, so set the boolean back to false
    _isGettingNewItems = false;
}
```

Comment: I believe this is exactly what i was looking for, thanks! as for GetResponse() not being async; I see the issue there and will make it async, but would it really matter since it's some child function of a task? the parent(UI) wouldn't block, right?

Comment: Since GetResponse calls async methods, it is best to make it async as well so it can be awaited. But technically, yes, since you wrapped it in a Task it might not have mattered, But it can clean up your code a bit if you do make it async, as in the above example, and also make FetchResults async, that way you don't have to wrap it in a Task.Run. Setting up new threads takes time, so whatever can be done to avoid unnecessary Task creation is a good thing for performance. IN fact, another look says that all you may really need to do is make FetchResults and GetResponse async.